# How to check if broadcast intent was send in Instrumentation test case?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing Espresso test case for camera app. In the test case I want to know, if picture is actually taken - if so, broadcast Intent "android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" will be sent.
I'm trying to use Espresso-intents library for this, but according to Espresso website, it can only match Intents that attempt to launch activities, not broadcast (https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/#intent-validation).

So, my question is: is it possible to catch broadcast intents within Espresso? Or s there other possibilities to catch such Intents in Instrumentation test case?